# JAR file changes in Lotus Notes database not being picked up by Domino server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a custom Java class that I created in Eclipse and exported as a JAR file. I imported it into a Notes database under WebContent\WEB-INF\lib and added to the build path. The JAR is being used from SSJS on an XPage using "importPackage" and all works well.

However, if I make changes to the Java code in Eclipse, recreate the JAR, re-import into the Notes database then the changes to the code are not being picked up when I reload the XPage. It doesn't seem to matter how many times I clean or rebuild the project the changes are not reflected until I restart the HTTP task on the Domino server (9.0.1 FP1).

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting HTTP server via "task restart http" is probably required. it is for changes to OSGI librarys / Ext. Librarys etc.

Comment: Thanks David. I had assumed (maybe incorrectly) that because the JAR is inside the .nsf that a clean / rebuild would pick up the changes.

Comment: I use jar files in a project and when they change a restart of HTTP is not needed

Comment: Per - I assumed that would be the case. Not sure what I am missing!